# For loop only going through one iteration

Tags: ti-basic

I am trying to create a program that simplifies radicals in TI-BASIC. However, one FOR loop seems to be only completing one iteration while the rest work fine. Here is the code:

```
Input "Root=",A
Input "Radical=",B
B→Z
ClrList L₃
prgmPRMNTOL1
prgmGETPRIME
```

The FOR loop in question starts here...

```
For(Y,1,10)
0→Z
For(X,1,dim(L₂))
If L₁(Y)=L₂(X)
Then
Z+1→Z
End:Disp Z
End
If Z≥A
Then
int(Z/A)*A→C
int(Z/A)→D
For(T,1,D)
L₁(Y)→L₃(1+dim(L₃))
End
For(R,1,C)
ClrList L₄
For(S,1,dim(L₂))
If L₂(S)=L₁(Y) and C>0
Then
–1→L₂(S)
C-1→C
End
End
For(Q,1,dim(L₂))
If L₂(Q)≠–1
Then
L₂(Q)→L₄(1+dim(L₄))
End
End
ClrList L₂
For(Q,1,dim(L₄))
L₄(Q)→L₂(Q)
End
End
End
```

...and ends here.

```
1→E
For(M,1,dim(L₃))
E*L₃(M)→E
End
1→F
For(N,1,dim(L₂))
F*L₂(N)→F
End
Disp "OUTSIDE",E,"ROOT",A,"INSIDE",F
```

The program works perfectly besides the fact that this one loop only runs once. I will post `prgmPRMNTOL1` and `prgmGETPRIME` as well if necessary, though they probably do not have any impact as they modify only `L₁` and `L₂`.

EDIT: Added a indented version.

```
Input "Root=",A
Input "Radical=",B
B→Z
ClrList L₃
prgmPRMNTOL1
prgmGETPRIME

For(Y,1,10)
    0→Z
    For(X,1,dim(L₂))
        If L₁(Y)=L₂(X)
        Then
            Z+1→Z
        End
    End
    If Z≥A
    Then
        int(Z/A)*A→C
        int(Z/A)→D
        For(T,1,D)
            L₁(Y)→L₃(1+dim(L₃))
        End
        For(R,1,C)
            ClrList L₄
            For(S,1,dim(L₂))
                If L₂(S)=L₁(Y)
                Then
                    –1→L₂(S)
                End
            End
        For(Q,1,dim(L₂))
            If L₂(Q)≠–1
            Then
                L₂(Q)→L₄(1+dim(L₄))
            End
        End
        ClrList L₂
        For(Q,1,dim(L₄))
            L₄(Q)→L₂(Q)
        End
    End
End

1→E
For(M,1,dim(L₃))
    E*L₃(M)→E
End

1→F
For(N,1,dim(L₂))
    F*L₂(N)→F
End

Disp "OUTSIDE",E,"ROOT",A,"INSIDE",F
```

Comment: A common reason for this behavior is that your loops and ends don't line up. An oindented version of your code would make this easy to detect.

Comment: @dohaqatar7 just added it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Close Your Loops

Your issue seems to stem from incorrectly matching your `If` statements, loops and their `End` statements.

### What's Happening

The behavior of TI-Basic when end of file is reached before all loops and `If` statements have been closed is to fail silently, terminating the program, rather than alerting the users of an error.

This behavior makes certain odd pieces of code syntactically valid. For instances this snippet would run without error:

```
 For(A,1,10
     Disp A
```

The results being

```
               1
            Done
```

Obviously this is the same as running `Disp 1` so, there's no reason to use this an your code. It serves only to make silent and annoying errors appear in code.

### The Fix

Assuming the indented version of your code represents how you want your loops to be nested, the code below should fix your problem.

```
Input "Root=",A
Input "Radical=",B
B→Z
ClrList L₃
prgmPRMNTOL1
prgmGETPRIME
For(Y,1,10)
0→Z
For(X,1,dim(L₂))
If L₁(Y)=L₂(X)
Z+1→Z
End
If Z≥A:Then
int(Z/A)*A→C
int(Z/A)→D
For(T,1,D)
L₁(Y)→L₃(1+dim(L₃))
End
For(R,1,C)
ClrList L₄
For(S,1,dim(L₂))
If L₂(S)=L₁(Y)
–1→L₂(S)
End
End:"Inserted this End
For(Q,1,dim(L₂))
If L₂(Q)≠–1
L₁(Q)→L₄(1+dim(L₄))
End
ClrList L₂
For(Q,1,dim(L₄))
L₄(Q)→L₂(Q)
End
End
End
1→E
For(M,1,dim(L₃))
E*L₃(M)→E
End
1→F
For(N,1,dim(L₂))
F*L₂(N)→F
End
Disp "OUTSIDE",E,"ROOT",A,"INSIDE",F
```

If that doesn't fix it, the missing `End` is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I did not even know the code could run with missing ends. Thanks!

Comment: I figured this was the problem. +1 for the speed!